# Object Type Assigned to Class

Tags: java

```
Object o = getRectangle();
if(o instanceof Rectangle){
     Rectangle r = (Rectangle) o;
}
```

In the event that getRectangle() returns a Rectangle (Rectangle of which is a class in my project), would I be able to assign Rectangle to the object like so?

Comment: Yes it works, you would see it for yourself if you tried ;-)

Comment: Sorry, at school right now. Just wanted to make sure it would work before I went home and tested it :) <3 Love your faces.

Comment: Why doesn't `getRectangle()` return a `Rectangle` or is this just an example?

Comment: You know, you can use http://www.ideone.com/ to test in case you don't have an IDE next to you.

Comment: @Luiggi And that's where all of my online class time went :D

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  The code you mentioned will work.

Casting of objects will always work if the original object is an instance of what it is being cast to.  Since you've already checked whether o is an instance of Rectangle, no problems here.

I'm more concerned with what you would do with Rectangle r.  The scope of variable r is entirely within the innermost if() statement.  Thus, if you would like to access r outside `if (o instanceof Rectangle)`, that is not possible unless you declare it outside the if statement.